# Console not staying open with getch() using C++ (windows 8)

Tags: c++, console

I'm new to C++ and can't figure out why my console won't stay open during execution.  I'm just tinkering around, but feel free to crucify bad habits.  Please help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("quantity\tCost\tTotal\n");
    printf("\a\a\a\a\aSkip a few lines, and beep ");
    printf("%s %c.", "You are kicking butt learning", 'C');

    getche();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use _getch()it should work

Comment: windows 8 shouldn't matter?

Comment: Maybe use `std::getchar()`, or `std::fgetc(stdin)`, either of which has the bonus of being part of the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

Use `system("pause");`
which displays a message `press any key to continue...` and waits for you.